# Custom EPiServer form: success message not showing as in HTML code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, episerver

I have a View for my custom form.

In the view I have the following section:

```
  <%-- area for showing Form's status or validation --%>
        <div class="container roi">
            <div class="Form__Status bg-pattern parallax-background">
                <div class="Form__Status__Message <%: statusDisplay %>" data-f-form-statusmessage>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h3>Vielen Dank!</h3>
                            <div class="row success-msg">
                                <div class="col-xs-3 center-block-xs col-sm-push-0 col-md-2">
                                    <div class="square mb-1">
                                        <div class="square-content circle bg-red">
                                            <img class="icon-centered" src="/Static/img/icons/icon_check_white.svg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                                    <p class="mt-1"> Übermittlung erfolgreich pp. </p>
                                    <p class="mt-1" style="color:red;"> <%= message %> </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

However when I test the form in my browser the success message looks like this:

```
<div class="container roi">
            <div class="Form__Status bg-pattern parallax-background">
                <div class="Form__Status__Message Form__Success__Message" data-f-form-statusmessage="">Übermittlung erfolgreich.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I customize the success message?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using [language files](https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/globalization/localizing-the-user-interface/) you can edit the tag `submitsuccess` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<languages>
    <language name="English" id="en">
        <episerver>
            <forms>
                <messages>
                    <formsubmission>
                        <submitsuccess>We got your form!</submitsuccess>
                    </formsubmission>
                </messages>
            </forms>
        <episerver>
    </language>
</languages>
```